# Not able to push an object into parent array by identifying the parent id of the object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, for-loop, push

I'm having a JSON array with properties as id and parentActivityId.

```
$scope.data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        activityName: "Drilling",
        parentActivityId: 0,
        items: [
            {
                id: 2,
                activityName: "Blasting",
                parentActivityId: 1,
                items: [
                    {
                        id: 3,
                        activityName: "Ann",
                        parentActivityId: 2,
                        items: [],

                    },
                    {
                        id: 4,
                        activityName: "Ann",
                        parentActivityId: 2,
                        items: [],

                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                id: 5,
                activityName: "Transport",
                parentActivityId: 1,
                items: [
                    {
                        id: 6,
                        activityName: "Daniel",
                        parentActivityId: 5,
                        items: [],
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

I would like to push a new item based on the `parentActiityId`.The new item will be having a new `id`.
Example:If my object is like this:

```
{
    id: 7,
    activityName: "Drilling",
    parentActivityId: 1,
    items: []
}
```

then my object will look like this..

```
 $scope.data = [
        {
            id: 1,
            activityName: "Drilling",
            parentActivityId: 0,
            items: [
                {
                    id: 2,
                    activityName: "Blasting",
                    parentActivityId: 1,
                    items: [
                        {
                            id: 3,
                            activityName: "Ann",
                            parentActivityId: 2,
                            items: [],

                        },
                        {
                            id: 4,
                            activityName: "Ann",
                            parentActivityId: 2,
                            items: [],

                        },
                    {
                         id: 7,
                         activityName: "Drilling",
                         parentActivityId: 2,
                         items: [],
                     }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    id: 5,
                    activityName: "Transport",
                    parentActivityId: 1,
                    items: [
                        {
                            id: 6,
                            activityName: "Daniel",
                            parentActivityId: 5,
                            items: [],
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ];
```

I tried by giving this for loop..

```
var arrObj = {
    id: 7,
    activityName: "Drilling",
    parentActivityId: 1,
    items: []
};

function populateObj(arrObj) {
   for (var i = 0; i < $scope.data.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.data[i].id == arrObj.parentActivityId) {
            $scope.data.push(arrObj);
        }
    }
};

populateObj(arrObj);
```

which will push only to the parent.I want to identify the child as well in the for loop and the push to the specific array object by identifying thr parentActivityId.Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a recursive proposal and [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
var data=[{id:1,activityName:"Drilling",parentActivityId:0,items:[{id:2,activityName:"Blasting",parentActivityId:1,items:[{id:3,activityName:"Ann",parentActivityId:2,items:[]},{id:4,activityName:"Ann",parentActivityId:2,items:[]}]},{id:5,activityName:"Transport",parentActivityId:1,items:[{id:6,activityName:"Daniel",parentActivityId:5,items:[]}]}]}],
    child = { id: 7, activityName: "Drilling", parentActivityId: 1, items: [] };

function getParent(r, a) {
    return a.id === child.parentActivityId ? a : a.items.reduce(getParent, r);
}

var node = data.reduce(getParent, {});
'items' in node && node.items.push(child);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(data, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: If there is no data ie., data=[].I'm not able  to add a new child element?

Comment: then you need `'if (items' in node) { node.items.push(child); } else { data.push(child); }`. but you have pay attention to the possible wrong `parentId`.

Comment: Thanks @Nina Scholz..Its working the way I need.Can you please explain your code.II'm not familiar with the reduce functionality.You can message me at mailmrmanoj@gmail.com

Comment: Also is there any way to get the total number of objects?Including the parent object

Comment: please have a look to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) they can better explain as i can. the total number of objects can counted with this small code :`function count(r, a) { return r + 1 + a.items.reduce(count, 0); } var nodeCount = data.reduce(count, 0);`. the `nodeCount` contains the number of nodes.

Comment: Awesome @Nina Scholz.Thanks a Ton!!

Comment: If I want to remove an object based on id from data will the same conditions apply??

Comment: @forgottofly, then you have to iterate over the object with an other function. you may ask an other question at so.

Comment: please find the question here.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32132222/deleting-an-object-based-on-the-id-in-javascript

Answer (score 2):

You were close to what you tried to achieve. This should do the trick:

```
var arrObj = {
    id: 7,
    activityName: "Drilling",
    parentActivityId: 1,
    items: []
};

function populateObj(data, arrObj) {
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i].id == arrObj.parentActivityId) {
            data[i].items.push(arrObj);
        } else {
            populateObj(data[i].items, arrObj);
        }
    }
};

populateObj(arrObj);
```

Comment: I wanted to check the inner objects as well which I 'm not doing in  if ($scope.data[i].id == arrObj.parentActivityId) .How to check if arrObj.parentActivityId exists inside the items array as well?

Comment: What it's the purpose of this check ?

Comment: If the parentActivityId is 7 then I have to check the objects inside items array as well

Comment: I don't understand where do you to push your new object. In the `items` array corresponding to the parentActivityId ? Why do you need to check the objects inside the `items` array?

Comment: If the parentActivityId is inside the items array I have to push inside items array

Comment: I've edited my code using recursive calls, it should be okay now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87370/discussion-between-forgottofly-and-erazihel).

Answer (score 0):

To check the objects inside items array as well,you can do something like this,

```
var objectList = [
        {
            id: 1,
            activityName: "Drilling",
            parentActivityId: 0,
            items: [
                {
                    id: 2,
                    activityName: "Blasting",
                    parentActivityId: 1,
                    items: [
                        {
                            id: 3,
                            activityName: "Ann",
                            parentActivityId: 2,
                            items: [],

                        },
                        {
                            id: 4,
                            activityName: "Ann",
                            parentActivityId: 2,
                            items: [],

                        },
                    {
                         id: 7,
                         activityName: "Drilling",
                         parentActivityId: 2,
                         items: [],
                     }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    id: 5,
                    activityName: "Transport",
                    parentActivityId: 1,
                    items: [
                        {
                            id: 6,
                            activityName: "Daniel",
                            parentActivityId: 5,
                            items: [],
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ];

var arrObj = {
    id: 7,
    activityName: "Drilling",
    parentActivityId: 1,
    items: []
};

function populateObj(ItemList) {
   for (var i = 0; i < ItemList.length; i++) {
        if (ItemList[i].id == arrObj.parentActivityId) {
            ItemList[i].items.push(arrObj);
        }
       else
       {
         populateObj(ItemList[i].items);
       }
    }
};

populateObj(objectList);
```