# Advice on creating a matrix table in angular JS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Below is my JSON object(partial) which I would like to show as a matrix table preferably using ng-repeat:

```
[
    {
        "product": "milk",
        "resource": "a",
        "checked": true
    },
    {
        "product": "bread",
        "resource": "a",
        "checked": false
    },
    {
        "product": "butter",
        "resource": "a",
        "checked": true
    }
]
```

[image]

I have tried http://plnkr.co/edit/iW1dZV?p=info but I don't want to use coffeescript.

Comment: you should make your Json valid first.

Comment: I have shown the first  3 items in JSON.They are correct..

Comment: Not according to this http://chris.photobooks.com/json/default.htm

Comment: Property names should be encapsulated in double quotes for valid JSON.

Comment: Anyway your json format the way it is can't be used for what you need. It should be in a different format if you want the table to be dynamic (not dependant to the data)

Comment: What can be the possible format?

Comment: @forgottofly will paste the json in an answer, too long for a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@forgottofly here is an example of better json for what you need:

```
[{
  "resource": "a",
  products: [{
    "product": "milk",
    "checked": true
  }, {
    "product": "bread",
    "checked": false
  }, {
    "product": "butter",
    "checked": true
  }]
}, {
  "resource": "b",
  products: [{
    "product": "milk",
    "checked": false
  }, {
    "product": "bread",
    "checked": true
  }, {
    "product": "butter",
    "checked": true
  }]
}, {
  "resource": "c",
  products: [{
    "product": "milk",
    "checked": false
  }, {
    "product": "bread",
    "checked": true
  }, {
    "product": "butter",
    "checked": true
  }]
}]
```

Comment: How can I iterate using ng-repeat to display this JSON?

Comment: Please check this plunker. http://plnkr.co/edit/9aZLqW0PzfgRvTl4UVwT?p=preview .Here I'm not able to display the data correctly.Please check where I'm doing wrong here

Comment: Please find the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32517107/not-able-to-display-correct-data-in-table-angularjs?noredirect=1#comment52892425_32517107

Comment: or with this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/CbyOFMgWoQ52n55Us4ys?p=preview how can I get the values from input text box on button click

Comment: How exactly you need the data to be stored? in initial json r in a separate object?

Answer (score 2):

No ng, but plain javascript.

Basically you need a function which returns the checked property of the array with the given properties. This function iterates over the elements until the property values are matched.

The second part is to generate the table, which should be easier in ng, as I think.

```js
function isChecked(product, resource) {
    return data.some(function (a) {
        if (a.product === product && a.resource === resource) {
            return a.checked;
        }
    });
}

var data = [
        {
            "product": "milk",
            "resource": "a",
            "checked": true
        },
        {
            "product": "bread",
            "resource": "a",
            "checked": false
        },
        {
            "product": "butter",
            "resource": "a",
            "checked": true
        }
    ],
    cols = ['milk', 'bread', 'butter', 'cheese', 'jam'],
    rows = ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    table = document.createElement("table"),
    tr = document.createElement("tr"),
    th = document.createElement("th"),
    td;

th.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
tr.appendChild(th);
cols.forEach(function (c, j) {
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = c;
    tr.appendChild(th);
});
table.appendChild(tr);
rows.forEach(function (r, i) {
    tr = document.createElement("tr");
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = r;
    tr.appendChild(td);
    cols.forEach(function (c, j) {
        td = document.createElement("td");
        td.innerHTML = +isChecked(c, r);
        tr.appendChild(td);
    });
    table.appendChild(tr);
});
document.getElementById('table').appendChild(table);
```

```html
<div id="table"></div>
```

Comment: please find this plunker in which I need to get individual values from the text box on click of save.  http://plnkr.co/edit/T0WJFs2b62GVbHzOxtzE?p=preview

Comment: or with this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/CbyOFMgWoQ52n55Us4ys?p=preview how can I get the values from input text box on button click

Comment: feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: This was the question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32781366/save-all-the-values-in-input-text-box-that-is-in-ng-repeat/32781638?noredirect=1#comment53404600_32781638

Comment: i have no idea of angular.js.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is not the exact solution for your problem, I hope this will give you idea of what needs to be done. I am printing the array based on sequence but you can change the condition easily.

### Convert an array into a matrix/ grid

I have an array which i wanted to convert into a grid/matrix  of column size 4. the following implementation worked for me. You can use the two counters : row and col as you like in side the nested ng-repeat

In my case number of columns is 3. But you can replace that 3 with a variable everywhere.  `h.seats` is my array of the objects and i want to  print either X or - based on value of element in that array

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th ng-repeat="n in [].constructor(3 + 1) track by $index">{{$index}}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="(row, y) in getNumber(h.seats.length, 3) track by $index">
                <td>{{row+1}}</td>
                <td class="text-primary"
                    ng-repeat="(col, t) in h.seats track by $index"
                    ng-if="col >= (row)*3 && col < (row+1)*3">
                        <span ng-show="t.status"> X </span> 
                        <span ng-show="!t.status"> - </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

`<th ng-repeat="n in [].constructor(3 + 1) track by $index">{{$index}}</th>` prints the header row with column number at the top. `getNumber(h.seats.length, 3)` returns me the number of rows of that table as follows

```
.controller('CustomViewController', function ($scope, Principal, $state) {

    $scope.getNumber = function(length, columns) {
        return new Array(parseInt(length / columns + 1, 10));   
    }
```

The line `ng-if="col >= (row)*3 && col < (row+1)*3"` is important logic to calculate which elements should be put in that row.
The output looks like below

```
0  1  2  3 
1  e1 e2 e3 
2  e4 e5 e6 
3  e7 e8
```

Refer to following link for details of how row and col counters are used: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/35566132/5076414